# snakeYaml refer to the same instance of an object multiple times

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

Inside of a list, I would like to refer to the same instance object multiple times:

```
- text: Here is an object with some data that will allow an image to be generated
  image: &FirstIm
      imageType: ABC
      otherTypE: CB
- text: Later on, lets show you the same image again!
  image: *FirstIm
```

What I'm doing is generating an image using the properties provided and caching it in the image object. Because of the specific implementation, I cannot generate the image again, so I would like to refer back to specific instances of an image object.

Unfortunately, snakeYAML treats the above as "oh, so you'd like another object, but with the same properties as FirstIm" so when I check the second image objects cache, there's nothing in it. The behaviour I need is "you want FirstIm again, ok, ill put that there".

Is there any way of achieving this without using some kind of string in the image object to refer to some higher level caching?

Hope this makes sense...

Comment: I am a SnakeYAML developer and I do not understand the question. What is 'when I check the second image objects cache' ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for being unclear. To break the problem down to hopefully be simpler - if "mylist" is the resulting object from  parsing that section of code above, I could do mylist.get(0).text which would give "Here is an object with...". If I do mylist.get(0).image.imagecache=someImageIMade then if I read mylist.get(1).image.imagecache I won't get back someImageIMade. So how can I tell snaleyaml "I want literally the same instance here"

Comment: Hi Andrey, just a quick, one, there was absolutely no issue with snakeYAML (have a look at my comments to maslovalex's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some issues in your code or I still do not understand the question, because yaml from your question passes test just fine.

Cannot put code in the comment. So here it is.

```
import java.util.List
import java.util.Map
...
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
List load = yaml.loadAs("- text: Here is an object with some data that will allow an image to be generated\n  image: &FirstIm\n    imageType: ABC\n    otherTypE: CB\n- text: Later on, lets show you the same image again!\n  image: *FirstIm", List.class);
assertSame(((Map)load.get(0)).get("image"), ((Map)load.get(1)).get("image"));
```

Comment: Right, you were bang on. Yaml is not my problem. I'm using the play framework and I believe it is trying to use magic to access the object over a number of threads, meaning the actual image generation is being done twice, how annoying. Damn that magic! Time for some careful use of synchronised methinks. Thanks very much for your help though maslovalex:)